# How to setup node-schedule for every day at 12am

Tags: node.js, npm, schedule

I am using node-schedule to schedule my tasks. Now I need to schedule a job everyday at 12am.
Below given is the code I am using,

```
var rule3 = schedule.scheduleJob('00 00 00 * * *', function(){
    console.log('my test job!');
});
```

This is not working for me.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this to verify here https://crontab.guru/  for Ex: schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 * * *', function() {});

Comment: You can check this link also https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/issues/251

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use **node-cron** module simply.

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('00 00 12 * * 0-6', function() {
  /*
   * Runs every day
   * at 12:00:00 AM.
   */
  }, function () {
    /* This function is executed when the job stops */
  },
  true, /* Start the job right now */
  timeZone /* Time zone of this job. */
);
```

Read [docs](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) for more pattern.

Comment: The last parameter should be 0-6 (Sun to Sat) instead of 1-7

Comment: Simply you can use '00 00 00 * * *'

Comment: The OP is using node-schedule library and not Cron.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is stuck on this also check what time your app is operating in. Your app by default might be in Greenwich Mean Time which would definitely make you think your schedule is not working. Toss a console.log(Date.now()) in a convenient location and check. You might just have to adjust the time on your schedule by a couple hours.